# How to utilize .manifest file associated with image file?

Tags: system-installation

I have noticed that there is an associated .manifest file with ubuntu image for downloading.

For example [here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/groovy/20210225/).

I am going to download groovy-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz and how to utilize groovy-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.manifest to help me?

Comment: Well, you can open it with a plain text editor and see what's on the image for software. I use one manifest to 'diff' against another manifest in the process of doing live beta testing for Lubuntu. It probably doesn't have much use for you other than looking to see what's there.

Comment: @KGIII I see the point. Thanks. I wonder if there is any tool to utilize it or genereate it.